# XQuery multiple outputs

Tags: xml, xquery

Im trying to output multiple things on XQuery from a xml file.

```
for $foo in doc("foo.xml")//foo/who
return $foo
for $bar in doc("bar.xml")//bar/too
where $foo/name=$too/name
return $too/title
```

so i can return $foo if i remove the other for section. if i remove the $foo i can return the $too/title.

i also cant figure out a way to return multiple from one return

```
return $too/title
           $too/name
           $too/date
```

does not work

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
return ($too/name, $too/title) etc.
Remember you are returning a sequence, which can be 0 (), one ($var) or more ($one,$two) items.
Just put them between () and separate with ,

Success

Comment: Hey thanks. quick q, say i have
return (
 $author/name,
 $author/born-died,
 $author/nationality,
 $author/biography) and i want to add <author> to the beggining and </author> to the end, how would i go about doing that?

Comment: dont worry, i have used "element author" after the return.
Thanks!

Comment: Remember XQuery is case sensitive, `Return` and `return` are not equivalent.